# TinyMCE image resizing mode

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE v.4.0.8 in inline mode.
I need to select image so that user can resize it. Object resizing is disabled in settings. When user presses my custom button, it enables object resizing and should select image to draw resize handles. I've tryed many different ways. This one works in Chrome, but does not work in Firefox:

```
// my image node is defined in 'img' variable
tinymce.activeEditor.settings.object_resizing = true;
img.click();     // jQuery(img).trigger('click')
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.collapse();
```

How can I make this code works in FF? I've tried to select image node by `selection.select(img)` and `selection.controlSelection.controlSelect(img)` - doesn work. Click event does not trigger on image at all in FF.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: could you create a tinymce fiddle for this?

Comment: It is here: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sHdaab

Comment: thx, if the user clickes on the image it works fine, but i am not able to get it per javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I've finally solved the problem. But i had to change ControlSelection class for this. To control the objects selection and to switch resizing mode we need to handle this methods: `showResizeRect()`, `hideResizeRect()`, `isResizable()`. And I just applied public access to them.